# Latest MySQL driver found in the remote repository

Tags: mysql, maven, database-connection, dependency-management

I installed mySQL database 5.6 and I want to include the dependence of the driver but I could not find the repository of this dependence (the latest version is 5.1).

If I download the driver (jar) and add it to the lib, in this case is there any tag to add to pom.xml to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 5.1.31 should work for you. You can find it in Maven Central Repository http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22mysql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mysql-connector-java%22